# How to send google spreadsheet input, Ignore Cell if Have Formula

Tags: javascript

[Goolge Siderbar Input Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0hh3.png)

When click submit, I want input form send data to colums A, B, E and F
Because in column C and D have formula..
anyone can help me? ..
Thanks

Source: https://www.bpwebs.com/creating-forms-in-google-sheets-sidebar-modal-dialog-forms/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick dirty solution you can change the functon `processForm()` in your Code.gs:

```
//PROCESS FORM
function processForm(formObject){ 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // set first two cells (columns A and B) of the last row
  sheet.appendRow([formObject.first_name, formObject.last_name]);
  // fil cell #4 (column D) in the row
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),4).setValue(formObject.email);
}
```

The same way you can put your formula in the cell #3 (column C). I believe there is a better solution as well, depending on your aims.

---

Updated version of the function. To insert a new inside the table after the first non empty cell in column 'A':

```
//PROCESS FORM
function processForm(formObject){ 
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();           // get sheet        
    var col   = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();         // get column A
    var row   = col.findIndex(c => c[0] == "") + 1;        // get the row num
    sheet.getRange(row,1).setValue(formObject.first_name); // set cell 1
    sheet.getRange(row,2).setValue(formObject.last_name);  // set cell 2
    sheet.getRange(row,4).setValue(formObject.email);      // set cell 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer. but now have one more problem (see Picture 1)
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxA84.jpg)
in pic1, when click submit, it not fill data in row 3

And I want result like Picture 2
[Picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayaJe.jpg)
when click submit, data result in row 3
next submit, data result in row 4
next submit, data result in row 5
etc

Comment: Of course, the method `appendRow` adds row at the end of existing table. If you need to add row inside the table (at the end column 'A' for example) you have to use another method. It's need to get range "A:A", to find the last non empty cell and insert your data in the next row. I'll show you how it can be done.

Comment: @Yuri Khristich, Done. Anyway, thanks for the function. It's been 5 days i am looking for the answer on google... finally ... Solved
Thanks Bro